# Visual Basic excel, How to ask for letter colors

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask for a letter color in an If conditional:

```
string="asdfghjkl"
for i=1 to len(string)
    letter = mid(string, i, 1)
    input_letter = inputbox("Write a letter")
    if letter = input_letter 'and letter.Font.Color = RGB(31,78,120)
        'my code here
    endif
next
```

The and letter.Font.Color = RGB(31,78,120) is not working. It says i need an object.

Is there any similar way to ask this? This RGB color is blue, and I am using this code to transform the entire sentence to blue (with the record macro excel setting)

```
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: RGB function returns Long, so in InputBox you can request this number. For instance, `RGB(112, 15, 210) = 13766512`.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding your question's problem:**

The `.Font.Color` is a property of the class `Range`, but in your line of code:

```
if letter = input_letter 'and letter.Font.Color = RGB(31,78,120)
```

... you're trying to access this property in the variable `letter`, which is a `String` (you don't explicitly declare it as such, but it gets automatically declared when you execute `letter = mid(string, i, 1)` just above).

That is why you get an `Object required` exception: you're trying to access the property `.Font.Color` on something that is not a `Range` object (actually, not an `Object` at all).

**Regarding your real need:**

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to reach a multi-colored text into a single cell in Excel? If I've got it right, you'll have a string:

```
string="asdfghjkl"
```

*(please note: you can't call your variable `String`, that's a reserved keyword for the code. Think of calling it something else, though I guess you already do that in your real code or you wouldn't be able to execute it at all).*

... and, for each letter of that string,

```
for i=1 to len(string)
```

... you want the user to give you a color. In that case, you can't do it in Excel. If not that, could you please express better your real need?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a little game.
It gets a random sentence from 5 written in another sheet, but this is already working. And asign it's value to sentence

sentence=range("B11").value


Then change the sentence color to blue, as the letters are hidden inside an excel cell.
Then I ask the user to enter a letter with the inputbox, and save it to input_letter.

So what I'm trying to do is to ask excel if input_letter is = to sentence letter and also if it's still in blue color.
When it finds a coincidence, changes the letter color to white.

Answer (score 0):

The code below comes closest to your OP logic and comment using the `.Characters` property of a cell `Range` (B11) containing your string value:

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim blue         As Long:   blue = RGB(31, 78, 120)
Dim s            As String: s = "asdfgh"
Dim letter       As String
Dim input_letter As String
Dim i            As Integer
Dim rng          As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B11")
With rng
  .Value = s
  ' color whole string
  .Characters(1, Len(s)).Font.Color = blue
  For i = 1 To Len(s)
    letter = Mid(s, i, 1)
    input_letter = InputBox("Write a letter")
    If letter = input_letter And .Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = blue Then
        'color found character
        .Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
    ElseIf input_letter = "" Then Exit For
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

**Notes**

Always use `Option Explicit`in your modules declaration head. So you would see that `String` isn't allowed as variable name as it's a function.

The extra color check in the `If` condition seems redundant, as characters so long    a r e    blue.

You seem to prefer repeated `InputBox`*es* within the `For` - `Next` loop, could be reduced to a single call.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
The reason I don't place the inputbox inside the for loop is becouse it should only ask for 1 letter every time you execute the code. So u press the button, enter the letter, and then same thing with next player.